# $\int_0^{2\pi} \left| \sum_{n\in \mathbb N} e^{-nt} e^{in\theta} \right| d\theta \leq C(t) C'$?

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Fix $t>0$, 
$$\int_0^{2\pi}  \left| \sum_{n\in \mathbb N} e^{-nt} e^{in\theta} \right| d\theta  \leq C(t) C'$$

where $C(t)$ is some constant depending on $t$ and $C'$ is some constant (independent of $t$).

> My question is: Can we expect to find $C(t)$,  I'm curious to know behavior of $C(t)$ at $t\to 0$ and $t \to \infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int_0^{2\pi} |\sum_ne^{-nt} e^{in\theta}|d\theta \leq (\int_0^{2\pi} |\sum_ne^{-nt} e^{in\theta}|^{2}d\theta)^{1/2} \sqrt {2\pi}\leq \sum_n e^{-2nt}\sqrt {2\pi}$. You can take $C'=\sqrt {2\pi}$  and $C(t)=\sum_n e^{-2nt}$. Even though $C(t)<\infty$ for all $t$ this function blows up as $t \to 0$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Triangle inequality shows
$$\left|\sum_{n\in \mathbb N} e^{-nt} e^{in\theta}\right|\leq \sum_{n\in \mathbb N}\left| e^{-nt} e^{in\theta}\right| = \sum_{n\in \mathbb N} e^{-nt} = \dfrac{1}{e^t-1}$$
for $t\geq0$.